# Unable to refresh ng-model values and variables from controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

I have some angular variables on my view part and want to update when its value gets changed from controller in real time. pager is my model and it get update by controller whenever setpage() function is called. I am posting my code here

**html**

```
<div class="col-sm-5 hidden-xs">
   <div class="dataTables_info" ng-model = "pager" id="example-datatables2_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">
      <strong>{{pager.startIndex}}</strong>-<strong>{{pager.endIndex + 1}}</strong> of <strong>{{list.count}}</strong>
   </div>
</div>
```

**controller**

```
app.controller('listController',function($scope,$http,PagerService){

    $scope.list = {};
    $scope.pager = {};
    $scope.setPage = setPage;
    $scope.list = response;
    $scope.pageSize = "10";

    initController();

    function initController() {
        $scope.setPage(1);
    }

    function setPage(page,pageSize) {
        if (page < 1 || page > $scope.pager.totalPages) {
            return;
        }
        $scope.pager = PagerService.GetPager($scope.list.count, page,pageSize);
        if($scope.default != 1){

            var data = {"session_id":session_id, "offset":$scope.pager.startIndex, "limit":$scope.pager.pageSize};

            apiCall(data,"reportRoute.php?action=select&id="+id).then(function (res) {
                $scope.list.data = res.data.data;
                $scope.list.count = res.data.count;
                $scope.list.default = res.data.default;

            });
        }

    }


    function apiCall(postData, postUrl){
        postUrl = 'https://example.com/routes/'+postUrl;
        //getData = {action:validate,id:id};
        return $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : postUrl,
            data    : postData,
            headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            //params  : getData
        })
    }

})
```

**pager object 1st time**

```
{totalItems: 33287, currentPage: 1, pageSize: 10, totalPages: 3329, startPage: 1,startIndex:0,endIndex:9}
```

**pager object when click on 2nd page of pagination**

```
{totalItems: 33287, currentPage: 1, pageSize: 10, totalPages: 3329, startPage: 1,startIndex:10,endIndex:19}
```

so in second click, the angular variables are not get updated in real time.

Comment: you can not bind `model` to div

Comment: ok so what can I do instead ?

Comment: do you want to create pagination?

Comment: Share the output json or take a look onto this [link](plnkr.co/edit/NqwW45ijaPqTaXDU21NP)

Comment: No @HJz. I have already created it. I want to just update some angular varibales when its actual value get changed.

Comment: maybe you should use `ng-init` instead of `ng-model`.please put more data.

Comment: I have updated the description @HJz

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller('listController',function($scope,$http,PagerService,$timeout){

    $scope.list = {};
    $scope.pager = {};
    $scope.setPage = setPage;
    $scope.list = response;
    $scope.pageSize = "10";

    initController();

    function initController() {
        $scope.setPage(1);
    }

    function setPage(page,pageSize) {
        if (page < 1 || page > $scope.pager.totalPages) {
            return;
        }
        $scope.pager = PagerService.GetPager($scope.list.count, page,pageSize);
        if($scope.default != 1){

            var data = {"session_id":session_id, "offset":$scope.pager.startIndex, "limit":$scope.pager.pageSize};

            apiCall(data,"reportRoute.php?action=select&id="+id).then(function (res) {
 $timeout(function(){
  $scope.list.data = res.data.data;
  $scope.list.count = res.data.count;
  $scope.list.default = res.data.default;
  $scope.pager.startIndex = data.offset;
 $scope.pager.pageSize = data.limit;
 },0)


            });
        }

    }


    function apiCall(postData, postUrl){
        postUrl = 'https://example.com/routes/'+postUrl;
        //getData = {action:validate,id:id};
        return $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url     : postUrl,
            data    : postData,
            headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            //params  : getData
        })
    }

})
```

Comment: what response containing,u are assigning to list?? and displaying pager in UI

Comment: check list.count value is displaying in ui or not??

Comment: count is showing there. but page startIndex and endIndex is not actually getting updated.

Comment: yes ,bz value is empty,can you display value of data @SaMeEr

Comment: check once @SaMeEr